# If I add new form elements (appendChild) a form, I can't add event

Tags: javascript

I made a program when you enter form field number, you can insert a plus input box if you fell, whem remove. A problem is that we have a for loop, where you can gather elements which the "validate" class is (these form fields). onblur event to add functions, but I can not solve that added new elements to the program take into account. I tried and I did arrays that included new elements into an array, but since the for loop is therefore outside the event, if you add it, you can do nothing happens.

If anyone can help that in that case, it wont solve this, I really appreciate it!
(A code is supplied, only a test, specifically focuses on this problem.)

```js
function onlyNumber(e) {
  var x = e.keyCode;

  if ((x >= 49 && x <= 57) || x === 9 || x === 8 || x === 46 || (x >= 97 && x <= 105)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function initOnlyNumber() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll('.onlynumber');
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].addEventListener('keydown', onlyNumber, false);
  }
}


var childNumber = document.querySelector('.childNumber');
childNumber.onkeyup = function() {
  var childNumberValue = childNumber.value;
  var childrens = document.querySelector('.childrens');
  var inputLengths = document.querySelectorAll('.kids');

  var inputLength = '';
  var element = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < inputLengths.length; i++) {
    var inputLength = inputLengths.length;
    var element = inputLengths[i];
  }

  var arrayElement = [];
  for (var i = inputLength; i < childNumberValue; i++) {

    var newElement = document.createElement('input');
    newElement.classList.add('kids');
    newElement.classList.add('validate');
    newElement.setAttribute('name', 'child-' + (i + 1));
    newElement.setAttribute('data-name', 'child-' + (i + 1));

    childrens.appendChild(newElement);
  }

  if (inputLength == 1) {
    if (childNumberValue == '') {
      childrens.removeChild(childrens.lastChild);
    }
  }

  if (childNumberValue > 0) {
    for (var i = inputLength; i > childNumberValue; i--) {
      childrens.removeChild(childrens.lastChild);
    }
  }
}




var validates = document.querySelectorAll('.validate');
for (var i = 0; i < validates.length; i++) {
  var validate = validates[i];

  validate.onblur = function(event) {
    obj = this;
    console.log(obj);
  }
}






window.onload = function() {
  initOnlyNumber();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
*:link,
*:hover,
*:visited,
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #4caf50 inset;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
input {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50px;
}
.childrens {
  display: inline-block;
}
.childrens input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.childNumber {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<form action="">

  <input class="validate onlynumber" name="name" type="text">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input class="validate onlynumber" name="email" type="text">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input class="validate onlynumber" name="tax" type="text">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input class="validate onlynumber" name="phone" type="text">
  <br />
  <br />

  <input class="childNumber onlynumber" name="childNumber" type="text" maxlength="1">

  <div class="childrens"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: please paste the relevant code.

Comment: `var validates = document.querySelectorAll('.validate');` is run before any of the (new) elements would've been added - so, there's your problem - asynchronous code